# Using Agile development when building websites

Tags: agile

Is it possible / plausible to apply Agile development to the website building process including planning, design and development?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Of course it is possible. A web site is just one of many types of software projects.

I'd even say that only Agile would work for a web project. Constant changes, continuous development, gradual feature addition and often redesign happen to accompany web development in most cases.